# Laravel - Proper way to support a URL piece that might have a slash in it?

Tags: php, laravel, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I've defined a route in web.php that looks like this:

`Route::delete('/app/charges-for-order/{orderId}', 'AppController@deleteOrderCharges');`

It seems to work well apart from when `orderId` has a forward slash in it. Eg `11/11`.

Naturally my first port of call was to generate the url in the frontend using `encodeURIComponent`:

`/app/charges-for-order/${encodeURIComponent(orderId)}` (in javascript)

Which produces the url `/app/charges-for-order/11%2F11`, replacing the forward slash with `%2F` -- however, this is giving me a 404, as if Laravel is still seeing %2F as a forward slash for routing purposes.

How can I allow `orderId` to have (encoded) forward slashes and still be part of the URL like that? Is there some alternate encoding scheme that Laravel will respect in this context?

Comment: Could you probably make an if statement at ServiceProviders to check if it has it or not? If yes you can clean it or so to fit your needs

Answer (score 2):

Use `where()` clause in route file. Which allows you to use RegEx in the file.

```
->where('orderId', '^[0-9/]+$'); # or
->where('orderId', '[0-9/]+'); # this
```

Read - [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

> **IMPORTANT: Do not use `->where('orderId', '.*')` or `->where('orderId', '.')` any cost.**

> **Side Note:** I'm not debugging the `DELETE` route works or not, just testing whether you can pass params. As well, if you found extensive RegEx, use it. I used this for testing purposes, but still, it does the job

---

I tested with `http://127.0.0.1:8090/app/charges-for-order/11/11` in my local, and the result was

[image]

Comment: does that include letters? `'^[0-9/]+$'`

Comment: no. if want add them

Comment: If you want you can add `A-Za-z` as I remember for text

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Apache as HTTP server? At least Apache is by default decoding `%2F` behind your back: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Changing this might be a bad idea, so I would suggest you would change your route to match all:

```php
Route::delete('/app/charges-for-order/{orderId}', 'AppController@deleteOrderCharges')
     ->where('orderId', '.+');
```

Comment: for some resaon, when i do this i get a really strange error: `"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE."` The route is still defined as a DELETE route, and I'm still calling it using the DELETE http method in my frontend. How strange

Comment: <edit> and that error doesn't happen when I dont supply an `orderId` with a slash in it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just changing the methods in question to accept query parameters or post data instead, I was having trouble with the other answers.